# Как написать условие?

Tags: php, if, условия

Есть часть содержимого php

```
<span class="tickets_span"> Количество пересадок: <?=$data['transfers'] ?></span>
```

Как написать условие в `PHP`:

Если <`?=$data['transfers'] ?>` равен нулю, то показать `"Без пересадок"`,
если `<?=$data['transfers'] ?>` больше нуля, то показать `<?=$data['transfers'] ?>`

Спасибо

Comment: `Количество пересадок: <?= $data['transfers'] > 0 ? $data['transfers'] : "Без пересадок" ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой открывающий тэг `<?=` не только обрамляет php-код, но и сразу же запускает вывод в HTML. Чтобы написать условие в `if` Вам нужен обычный открывающий тэг `<?php`:

```
<?php if($data['transfers'] == 0) echo "Без пересадок"; else echo $data['transfers']; ?>
```

Если Вам не нравятся лишние языковые конструкции echo, то можно продолжать использовать `<?=` для вывода, а в обычных обрамляющих php-код тэгах записать только условие. Вот пример (используется альтернативный синтаксис для `if`):

```
<?php if($data['transfers'] == 0): ?> Без пересадок <?php else: ?> <?= $data['transfers'] ?> <?php endif; ?>
```

На мой взгляд, `echo` смотрятся куда лучше, чем множество открывающих/закрывающих тэгов, когда надо выводить только динамическое содержимое. Но тут есть и статическое содержимое. Поэтому тут дело вкуса.
Также можно использовать тернарный оператор вместо `if`:

```
<?= ($data['transfers'] == 0)? "Без пересадок" : $data['transfers'] ?>
```

Comment: Во втором примере неверный вывод. Если равно 0 надо выводить текст, а не значение.

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($data['transfers'] == 0) {
       echo "Без пересадок";
   }elseif ($data['transfers'] > 0) {
       echo $data['transfers'];
  }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можете написать в одну функцию и использовать в любом месте:

```
<?php
function getTransfer($transfer){
    if ($transfer === 0) {$transfer = "Без пересадок";} else{
        $transfer = $transfer;
    }
    return $transfer;
}
?>

<span class="tickets_span"> Количество пересадок: <?php echo getTransfer($data['transfers']);  ?></span>
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/12iAS

Comment: идея с функцией хорошая, но код какой-то глупый. Какой смысл писать  $transfer = $transfer?

Comment: Потому что если переменная $transfer не равно нулю значить оно имеет какое то свое значение

Comment: Да какая разница, имеет или не имеет. Я спрашиваю, ЗАЧЕМ писать бессмысленный код? Присваивать переменной то самое значение, которое у неё УЖЕ ЕСТЬ?

Comment: Тот, кто поставил этому ответу +1 думает что сделал доброе дело. Но на самом деле все наоборот. плохие ответы поощрять нельзя, даже из самых добреньких побуждений